# HTTP status code for invalid format

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-codes

Our system is accepting a text file upload and is supposed to have a pre-determined line count. If the line count doesn't match up, I want to send a warning of sorts back to the user asking to confirm that they want to upload anyway.

Is there a particular status code I can use for something like this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use **422**.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
>   instructions.

You can check this out.

[rest API Tutorial - HTTP Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)